# FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JS heap out of memory

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4, webpack-5

I'm working in a React project using ***React 17.0.2*** and ***Webpack 5.28.0***, when I'm running my local server, once in a while the server shutsdown with no reason and I get this strange output in my terminal:

```
   <--- Last few GCs --->
    
    [87730:0x1046cc000]  4050109 ms: Scavenge 4059.3 (4100.1) -> 4053.3 (4100.1) MB, 2.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.193, current mu = 0.162) allocation failure
    [87730:0x1046cc000]  4050131 ms: Scavenge 4060.3 (4116.1) -> 4054.9 (4116.1) MB, 3.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.193, current mu = 0.162) allocation failure
    [87730:0x1046cc000]  4050174 ms: Scavenge 4069.5 (4116.1) -> 4057.6 (4117.1) MB, 5.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.193, current mu = 0.162) allocation failure
    
    
    <--- JS stacktrace --->
    
    FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
     1: 0x1012e4da5 node::Abort() (.cold.1) [/Users/eloi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
     2: 0x1000a6239 node::Abort() [/Users/eloi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
     3: 0x1000a639f node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/Users/eloi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
     4: 0x1001e9007 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/eloi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
     5: 0x1001e8fa3 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/eloi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
     6: 0x100397e95 v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*) [/Users/eloi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
     7: 0x10039995a v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [/Users/eloi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
     8: 0x100395029 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/Users/eloi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
     9: 0x1003928c1 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/Users/eloi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
    10: 0x100391838 v8::internal::Heap::HandleGCRequest() [/Users/eloi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
    11: 0x10034da51 v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts() [/Users/eloi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
    12: 0x1006ecf37 v8::internal::Runtime_StackGuardWithGap(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/Users/eloi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
    13: 0x100a7a239 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_NoBuiltinExit [/Users/eloi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
    /bin/sh: line 1: 87730 Abort trap: 6           webpack serve --progress --profile --color
    
    error Command failed with exit code 134.
```

It's quite annoying given that I have to be running the server from scratch all the time.

Anyone experienced the same issue?

Any idea on how to fix it?

Thanks

Using ***Node v15.11.0***